# How to fetch user and page/company posts from linkedin

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I have been checking the available linkedin API methods but cant see on how to fetch post by user and by page/company. What I need to do is that, user can enter username or a page/company name then, fetch news posts by it. Maybe you know some workarounds. Thanks

References:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api
https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?authTypeVal=oauth2&afterSuccessfulAuth=true

Answer (score 4):

Since October 2016 Linkedin updated the API an restricted actions to sign in, share content and manage companies, so you only can fetch the company's posts.

If you already have the user(company's admin) token access use this endpoint for get the posts of the page:

```
GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?format=json"
```

Comment: Link only answers can get invalidated in future. Request you to please add some context into your post from the link you have shared.

Comment: Seriously you put link to the API doc homepage?

Comment: Yes it was a mistake at that time the homepage had the alert for the changes but its a bad reference for the long run and now I dont find online docs for the v1 of the API so I removed the link.

Answer (score 0):

> [Detail Infomation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)
>   For search user

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
```

Method : GET

1. Add a format=json URL argument to the end of your API call.
2. Add this
       HTTP header to your API call: x-li-format: json